# Prax: failed to create symbolic link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use **Prax** for the first time to work with subdomains for my Ruby on Rails application. I have successfully installed it by following this guide

```
sudo git clone git://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax.git /opt/prax
cd /opt/prax/
./bin/prax install
```

but when I try to link my app with `Prax` by running

```
ln -s ~/Workfolder/myapp
```

I get the error:

> ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/username/.prax/myapp': Permission denied.

I have done some research but nothing seems to work. I need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it. All I needed to do was to run the command with administrative rights.

Firstly follow these steps to install prax

```
sudo git clone git://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax.git /opt/prax
cd /opt/prax/
./bin/prax install
```

OR

```
cd /tmp
wget https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax.cr/releases/download/v0.8.0/prax_0.8.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i prax_0.8.0-1_amd64.deb
```

And then create the symbolic link with your desired application by running the code below in your terminal.

```
cd /opt/prax
sudo ln -s ~/Workfolder/myapp
firefox http://myapp.dev
```

You can also link the same application under different names. All requests to those domains will be proxied to the same app. It also works for subdomains: pointing your browser to sub.myapp.dev will simply proxy the request to myapp.dev.

```
ln -s ~/Workfolder/myapp otherappname
firefox http://subdomain.otherappname.dev
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**